# Can you make anyons in 3 dimensions using rings?

Tags: mathematics, topological-quantum-computing, anyons

I heard that anyons can only be made in 2 dimensions because when you visualize the spacetime diagram of a 2-dimensional system with point particles, you can get braids, but if you do the same with a 3-dimensional system, you get only the un-braid since all braids can be unbraided in 4 dimensions.

But we can make braided surfaces in 4-dimensions by moving around rings in 3 dimensions! So does that mean we get 3 dimensional anyons if there are rings that behave like point-particle anyons?

I tried googling the keywords, but got no answers. I did find a video talking about braided surfaces using rings [(Braids in Higher Dimensions - Numberphile)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G_uybVKBacI).

Answer (score 5):

Indeed -- in theory, at least -- anyonic statistics does not so much require the ambient space to be 2-dimensional, as it requires the anyonic defects to have *co-dimension* 2 (hence dimension 2 less than that of the ambient space).

To give an impression, the following is a list of a few articles that consider 1-dimensional anyons (anyonic strings) in 3(+1) ambient dimensions (all in theory  -- there is nothing yet on this in experiment/engineering, as far as I am aware, even though it is quite conceivable that anyonic string defects can exist in realistic materials):

- J. Baez, D. Wise, A. Crans: "Exotic Statistics for Strings in 4d BF Theory", Adv. Theor. Math. Phys. **11** (2007) 707-749  ([arXiv:gr-qc/0603085](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0603085))
- A. Bullivant, J. F. Martins, P. Martin: "Representations of the Loop Braid Group and Aharonov-Bohm like effects in discrete (3+1)-dimensional higher gauge theory", Advances in Theoretical and Mathematical Physics **23** 7 (2019)  ([arXiv:1807.09551](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.09551))
- L. Kong, Y. Tian, Z.-H Zhang: "Defects in the 3-dimensional toric code model form a braided fusion 2-category", J. High Energ. Phys. **2020** 78 (2020) ([arXiv:2009.06564](https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.06564))

In mathematical terms, passage from point-like anyons in 2(+1) dimensions to string-like anyons in 3(+1) dimensions corresponds to passing from the braid group (and its representations) to the "[loop braid group](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/loop+braid+group)" (pointer to an nLab page that I once wrote). This might also be called the "string braid group".

Going further up to any ambient dimension, a "$p$-brane" in $(p+2)(+1)$ dimensions -- often called a "[defect brane](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/defect%20brane)" -- is expected to exhibit anyonic statistics, see for instance p. 65 of:

- J. de Boer, M. Shigemori: "Exotic Branes in String Theory", Physics Reports **532** (2013) 65-118 ([arXiv:1209.6056](https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.6056))

I am taking the liberty of closing by mentioning that just today we presented a proof of this expectation (assuming common hypotheses on the general mathematical rules of brane charges):

- H. Sati, U. Schreiber: "Anyonic Defect Branes and Conformal Blocks in Twisted Equivariant Differential (TED) K-theory" ([arXiv:2203.11838](https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.11838), [nLab](http://ncatlab.org/schreiber/show/Anyonic+defect+branes+in+TED-K-theory))

Answer (score 3):

In 3 dimensions, you can have both point particles and loops/rings/strings (all mean the same thing). There are several known braiding processes involving these two kinds of objects:

1. A particle can move around a string.
2. If there are two loops, one can "thread" one through the other to braid them. But this is actually not different from 1: the process can be smoothly deformed to the process 1 by first shrinking the loop to a point.
3. More interestingly, imagine there are three loops, two of them are linked to the third. Then we can do braiding 2 to the the two loops. Because of the third loop, now the deformation from 2 to 1 is no longer possible: we can not shrink any of the linked loop to a point without hitting another one. So this is in some sense a new braiding for loops in 3D.

The three-loop braiding process has been studied quite extensively in the context of topological phases in 3+1. All of above are basically taken from the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.7437.